# UseExceptionHandler won't catch tasks exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a simple webapi .net core 3.1 app.

I want to catch all unhandled exceptions.So I put this code according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda) :

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(c => c.Run(async context =>
{
    var exception = context.Features
        .Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>()
        .Error;
    var response = new { error = exception.Message };
    log.LogDebug(exception.Message);
}));
```

This is my action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    throw new Exception("this is a test");
}
```

When this code runs, I *do* see that `UseExceptionHandler` is working.

But when my code in the action is :

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        throw new Exception("this is a test");
    });
       
    return Ok();
}
```

Then `UseExceptionHandler` is *NOT* working.

However - the following code *does* catch the task's exception :

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Exception.ToString());
 };
```

**Question:**

- Why does the task exception isn't recognized by `UseExceptionHandler`?
- How can I catch ALL types of exceptions? Should I rely only on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`?

*nb , I did disabled `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`*

Comment: It's not about UseExceptionHandler, but about Exception Handling in TPL generally. Take a look:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library

Comment: You're not awaiting the task from `Task.Run`, so the exception is in that task, but it is lost since you never awaited it.

Comment: Where are you registering the event with "+=" before the receive data.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean ? It should be registered here in the first place in pipline so when it's back , there will be a ready registration : https://i.imgur.com/oF9R6hl.jpg

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's exactly what i'm after. catching non awaited tasks exceptions in a centelized place

Comment: Put a break point and see if you are getting to the registration before you do the Get.

Comment: @jdweng The first arrow is being hit after Task exception.. the second one , is not https://i.imgur.com/wYEGaMp.jpg  ( the second one is hit only if non task exception)

Comment: The route is not found does not automatically create an exception.  Use a DEFAULT Route and put exception in the default.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: @RoyiNamir what isn't working is the `Get` action. That task will start executing *after* the action exits and the request completes. No middleware will even know about that orphaned task. Why is `Task.Run` used like this? This is probably generating a compiler warning already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We put Task,Run there becuase we want to do something in background. Now that u say it , I can see that no one will know about this orphan task. So is this AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException the right way ? beucase it does catch the excaption

Comment: This is 100% an XY Problem. The real problem is how to execute long running tasks in he background. The answer is to use a hosted service, typically through a BackgroundService. The documentation shows how to create queued or timed services and pass data to them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. However , the main core origin reason -  besides the option that there is another way of doing it , is to KNOW why does first approach doesnt catch exceptions and the other  , does catch exceptions. Anyway , Now I understand :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir the reason is that the task runs outside the request pipeline, so `UseExceptionHandler` won't see any errors. I posted a *reduced* example of a queued background service I'm using right now, using Channel<T> as the async queue implementation. A real example would need lots of extra logging, a way to track the status of jobs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this particular symptom is that `Get` is starting a fire-and-forget task that the server knows nothing about. The request will complete before the task even has a chance to execute, so the `UseExceptionHandler` middleware will never see any exceptions. This is no longer a fire-and-*forget* task.

The *real* problem though, is executing a long running task in the background.  The built-in way to do this is using a [Background Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). The docs show how to create timed and queued background service, that act as job queues.

It's equally easy, if not easier, to publish messages with the desired data from, eg a controller to the background service using, eg Channels. No need to create our own queue, when the BCL already has an asynchronous one.

The service could look like this :

```
public class MyService: BackgroundService 
{

    private readonly ChannelReader<T> _reader;

    public QueuedBspService(MessageQueue<T> queue)
    {
        _reader = queue.Reader;
    }

    protected internal async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await foreach (var msg in _reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
            {                    

                try
                {
                    //Process the message here
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    //Handle message-specific errors
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //Handle cancellations and other critical errors
        }
    }
}
```

The `MessageQueue<T>` wraps the `Channel`, making it easier to inject it to both the BackgroundService and any publishers like eg, a Controller action:

```
public class MessageQueue<T> 
{
    private readonly Channel<T> _channel;

    public ChannelReader<T> Reader => _channel;
    public ChannelWriter<T> Writer => _channel;

    public MessageChannel()
    {
        _channel = Channel.CreateBounded<T>(1);
    }
}
```

I adjusted this code from a service that only allows a single operation at a time. That's a quick&dirty way of preventing controllers from making requests that can't be handled.

On the contolle side, this action will post a request to the queue if possible, and return a `Busy` response otherwise :

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ChannelWriter<T> _writer;


    public MyController(MessaggeQueue<T> queue)
    {
        _writer = queue.Writer;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(....)
    {
        var jobName="SomeJob";
        var id=Guid.NewGuid();
        var jobMsg=CreateMessage(id,...);


        try
        {
            if (_writer.TryWrite(msg))
            {
                return CreatedAtAction("GetItem","Jobs",new {id});
            }
            else
            {
                return Problem(statusCode:(int) HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable,detail:"Jobs in progress",title:"Busy");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exc,"Queueing {job} failed",jobName);
            throw;
        }
    }            
}
```

The `Post` action first checks if it can even post a job message. If it succeeds, it returns a `201 - Created` response with a URL that could be checked eg to check the status of the jobs. `return Created()` could be used instead, but once you create a long running job, you also want to check its status.

If the channel is at capacity, the core returns `503` with an explanation

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions.

*Why does the task exception isn't recognized by UseExceptionHandler?*

As already suggested in the comments, you cannot use `UseExceptionHandler` to catch exceptions initiated inside non-awaited tasks. `UseExceptionHandler` wraps your request in ASP.NET Core middleware. Once the action returns `OK` to the client, the middleware is no longer able to catch any exceptions happening in tasks started from within the action.

*How can I catch ALL types of exceptions? Should I rely only on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException?*

You can catch exceptions globally and log them this way if you'd like. But I wouldn't recommend you to do it this way. The only reason you need to implement this event, is that you are starting tasks/threads inside your web requests. You have no way of knowing if these tasks are kept running (application restart, recycle, etc.). If you are looking to launch background tasks with ASP.NET Core, you should use Worker Services which is the intended way of doing this:

```cs
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<MyWorker>();
});
```

```cs
public class MyWorker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do work
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Log it?
            }

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Task.Run in my code i specific to the request. e.g - i'm sending an AWS event . and don't want that user will suffr from this request/response time. So we put it in Task.run....Background service is for things which untight with request.

Comment: @RoyiNamir BackgroundService is for any kind of long running services. You only need to pass the data you want to the service. The docs show how to do this using, eg a queued service.

Comment: I've used backgroundservice / IHostedservice quite a lot. But never thought of connecting those two via queue. it can be option. Thank you:-)

Comment: Exactly. That's what I have done here: https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore/tree/main/src/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore. If you check out the code there's a piece of middleware putting an action on a queue: https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore/blob/main/src/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore/MessageShipper.cs#L50. And a hosted service processes messages from the queue.